# Alien Invasion Python Crash Course | After firing bullets, the ship starts slowing down

Tags: python, python-3.x

There's no error in the code. I've fixed lots of errors before but it doesn't pop up any error. I've also checked the game_functions to see if it had something do to with that, but everything seems to be perfectly fine.

The error is that when I click the spacebar to shoot the bullets, the ship starts slowing down.

main code (alien_invasion.py):

```
import sys
import game_functions as gf
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from pygame.sprite import Group



def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()



    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    # Make a ship.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
    bullets = Group()

    # Background color
    bg_color = (230, 230, 230)


    while True:

        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship)

        ship.update(ai_settings)
        bullets.update()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

        ship.blitme(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Bullet code (bullet.py):

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.sprite import Sprite
    
    class Bullet(Sprite):
    
        def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
            super().__init__()
            self.screen = screen
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, ai_settings.bullet_height)
            self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
            self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
            self.y = float(self.rect.y)
            self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
            self.ship_speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor
    
        def update(self):
            self.y -= self.ship_speed_factor
            self.rect.y = self.y
    
    
        def draw_bullet(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

game_functions.py:

```
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet

def check_keydown_events(event, ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        new_bullet =  Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event,ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = True

            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
           if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
             ship.moving_right = False

           elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
             ship.moving_left = False



def update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship):

    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
        ship.blitme(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

settings code (settings.py):

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 10

        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 12
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullet_limit = 5
```

ship code (ship.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
class Ship(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        super(Ship, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor



    def update(self, ai_settings):
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.rect.centerx += 1
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
            self.rect.centerx -= 1


    def blitme(self, screen):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Any help I would really appreciate it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `update_screen` function looks suspicious here - redrawing the ship and flipping the display for every bullet is probably not what was intended. Moving those lines outside the loop should help:

```
def update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship):

    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()

    ship.blitme(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```